# detect link click going to external url and display "warning"

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using MVC 3 with razor views and was curious if there was a way to generate either using the global.asax, web.config or some other global override to detect when a user is leaving the domain.  I'm required to place a alert, modal window or something explaining that we aren't responsible for the content on the next site (blah, blah Bob Boblaw).

I know there are ways with jquery and I could pop an alert box, but was hoping there was a way to do this with .NET.  This is my first site using MVC3 and it seems like routing or something powerful in the framework could do this.  Nothing similar comes up in a Google search.

Comment: To browse away with a link is made by the browser and server code has nothing to do with it. What you can do is to replace **all** links (for example using something like $("a") then changing href) to point to a JavaScript function. It'll check the address and then display the proper message/redirect to a confirmation page. Of course it can't handle changes made via code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change all external links to go via a local URL and an intermediary page.

or

You do it with Javascript. But you said you didn't want that, you wanted to do it with .NET, and hence you need to do it with an intermediary page.

Ideally, you should do *both*, so that if you don't have JS enabled, you get an intermediary page.

Comment: In my last site (classic asp), I would run all links through an intermediary page and then meta refresh to auto redirect.  It was cumbersome because some links would get borked because of case sensitivity.  Also, our security review vendor would complain that it was a redirect abuse and possible attack vector.  I'd rather not deal with it if I could help it.

Comment: Well, then you need to do it with Javascript. That's the options you have.

Comment: I never said I didn't want to do that, I was HOPING that there was a way to do it with .NET or the routing engine of MVC3.  If it was/is possible with MVC, I could use a partial view and other tricks.  It is about learning new ways.  Thanks for your replies.